# Spring Formatter for input field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, formatter

I have a question about the formatter in Spring.

I have a Formatter for my select boxes, for example:

```
public class SportTypeFormatter implements Formatter<SportType> {

    @Autowired
    private SportTypeRepository sportTypeRepository;

    @Override
    public String print(SportType sportType, Locale locale) {
        return String.valueOf(sportType.getTypeId());
    }

    @Override
    public SportType parse(String sportTypeId, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return sportTypeRepository.findSportTypeByTypeId(Long.valueOf(sportTypeId));
    }
}
```

in thymeleaf something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sportTypeId" th:field="*{person.sport.sportType}">
    <option th:each="spoType : ${allSportTypes}" th:value="${spoType.typeId}" th:selected="${spoType.typeId == person.sport.sportType}" th:text="#{${'login.sport.sportType.' + spo.typeId}}" >Sporttype</option>
</select>
```

Thats easy, because i only need one value (the id) and i'm going with select-box.

But what is if i need two values?

Suggest i have Email, there i need the id and the value (mail-address). I can build an Formatter for email but i have no chance to transfer the email and id at the same time.

In the print method i can something like that:

```
@Override
public String print(Email email, Locale locale) {
    return email.getId() + email.getEmail();
}
```

in thymeleaf:

```
<input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{{person.email}}" th:placeholder="#{login.email}" />
```

But with this the user can see the id.

If i do the binding the "standard" Spring way i get the following exception (thats the reason why i use the formatter):

```
{timestamp=Wed Dec 10 11:14:47 CET 2014, status=400, error=Bad Request, exception=org.springframework.validation.BindException, 
 errors=[Field error in object 'person' on field 'email': rejected value [com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email@0]; 
 codes [typeMismatch.person.email,typeMismatch.person.institutionEmployees.email,
        typeMismatch.email,typeMismatch.email,
        typeMismatch.email,typeMismatch.com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email,typeMismatch]; 
 arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
            codes [person.email,email]; 
            arguments []; 
            default message [email]]; 
            default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email' 
                             to required type 'com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email' 
                             for property 'email'; 
                             nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
                             Failed to convert from type com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email 
                             to type @javax.persistence.OneToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn @com.google.gson.annotations.Expose 
                                     com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email for value 
                                     'com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email@0'; 
                            nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
                                     Provided id of the wrong type for class com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email. 
                                     Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String; 
                            nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
                                     Provided id of the wrong type for class com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email. 
                                     Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String]], 
                                     message=Validation failed for object='person'. Error count: 1, path=/manageUsers/Ab-Soul/edit}
```

Any suggestion are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

**1. EDIT:**

The Controller-method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editUserByLogin(@PathVariable("login") final String login) {
    final User currentUser = UserRepository.findPersonByLogin(login);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(URL_EDIT_USER);
    mav.addObject(MODEL_USER, currentUser);

    return mav;
}
```

the scenario, the 'admin' get a list of all current user, if he clicked on the table the requestmapping-method would be called with the name of the user he has clicked.

the email class:

```
@Entity(name="Email")
public class Email implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6891079722082340011L;

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Expose
    protected Long emailId;
    @Expose
    protected String value;

    //getter/setter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj instanceof Email){
            return value.equals(((Email) obj).getValue());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return value.hashCode();
    }
}
```

**2. EDIT:**

Now i have change the email field of child to emailChild

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'person' on field 'child[0].emailChild': 
rejected value [com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email@0]; 
codes [typeMismatch.person.child[0].emailChild,
       typeMismatch.person.child.emailChild,
       typeMismatch.child[0].emailChild,
       typeMismatch.child.emailChild,
       typeMismatch.emailChild,
       typeMismatch.com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email,typeMismatch];
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
    codes [person.child[0].emailChild,child[0].emailChild]; 
arguments []; 
default message [child[0].emailChild]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email' to required type 'com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email' 
       for property 'child[0].emailChild'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email
to type @javax.persistence.OneToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn @com.google.gson.annotations.Expose com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email 
for value 'com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email@0'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.sample.persistence.user.model.Email. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String]
```

**3. EDIT:**

Adding the controller method for the post:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateUser(@PathVariable("login") final String login, @ModelAttribute(MODEL_USER) final Person person, BindingResult bindingResult,  final Model model) {
    Person repositoryPerson = personRepository.findPersonByLogin(login);

    repositoryPerson = repositoryPerson.updateWith(person);
    manageUserService.updatePerson(repositoryPerson);

    model.asMap().clear();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + URL_USERS_OVERVIEW, MODEL, model);
}
```

Comment: The "standard" Spring way is the best approach, could you please include your Email object details, the controller and the html page? Do you have this issue only when performing an edit or also when you create a new user?

Comment: @PatrickLC sorry for the late response, but i have the data not at home. If i create a new user i have an other structure, there is the following structure by registration: Person -> Child -> email and in edit (where the error occurs): Person -> List<Child> -> email

Comment: If you  try to edit a Person with only one Child and an associated email works fine?

Comment: No, then I get the error. If I edit the email from the person it will work for person. The point what me confuse, the email object from person and child are the same.

Comment: In order to clarify, could you change the email field name of the Child class to something like emailChild and post the exception again?

Comment: @PatrickLC i have do the changes you suggest, in the second edit you can see the next error.

Comment: Great, could you also include the controller for the post method?

Comment: Try to include in your controller @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("emailId");
    } Also before updating the Person, try to check there if the object retrieved from the model have all the modified data.

Comment: @PatrickLC i have thought about your suggestion. With your suggestion i say spring that he should ignore or not bind that field (emailId). Conclusion thats similar the same to the formattter (if i take onlye the email-address, not the id in the print method).

Comment: Great news! :) I think that's a perfect solution, someone also have a similar issue with complex objects binding (just for reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895406/spring-mvc-binding-complex-objects-to-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question.

We should remember that

- the registration process works fine, it would bind fine

Only the Problem occurs by the edit process, so i have a valid Email-Object in the db, bind with a valid Child-Object and this is bind with a valid User-Object.

I have decided to build a `EmailFormatter` with the following implemenatation:

```
public class EmailFormatter implements Formatter<Email> {

    @Override
    public String print(Email email, Locale locale) {
        return email.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Email parse(String mailAddress, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return new Email(mailAddress);
    }

}
```

with this, i get in my Child-Instance a new Email-Object (without the id). Now i have a valid Email-Object in a valid Child-Object. Take a look at the post-Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateUser(@PathVariable("login") final String login, @ModelAttribute(MODEL_USER) final Person person, BindingResult bindingResult,  final Model model) {
    Person repositoryPerson = personRepository.findPersonByLogin(login);

    repositoryPerson = repositoryPerson.updateWith(person);
    manageUserService.updatePerson(repositoryPerson);

    model.asMap().clear();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + URL_USERS_OVERVIEW, MODEL, model);
}
```

At this time i have the login name from the user, i get the "old" (valid) user-Object from the db. I have wrote a "merge" method, i give the "old" user object the modified user object.

Here i can get the old Email Object with id and set the email-adress just like this:

```
this.emailChild.setValue(modifiedChild.getemailChild().getValue());
```

After this i look at this solution, i notice thats really simple.

But if the binding problem occurs by a "complexer" (more then one relevant field) object then, i think, you go better white the solution that PatrickLC suggest:

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("emailId");
}
```